# OpenGL: GL_QUADS does not draw square

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, glu

I'm trying to draw a square on the screen but it clearly draws a rectangle.

[image]

This is my render code:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glTranslatef(0,0,-0.1);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(0,0,0);
    glVertex3f(1,0,0);
    glVertex3f(1,1,0);
    glVertex3f(0,1,0);
glEnd();

SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
```

And OpenGL Init code:

```
glClearColor(0,0,0,0.6f);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(30,640.0/480.0,.3f,200.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: maybe your screens horizontal dpi does not match vertical dpi ?

Comment: The dpi of the screen would not affect his screenshot though.

Comment: I don't know what I did but it's now drawing the square normally. I didn't change anything so I don't know what was wrong. Just the universe trolling me I guess :(

Comment: Is your window size 640x480 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see anywhere in your code where you have set-up the glViewport. I will rather write something like this in your init method:

```
glViewport(0,0,640,480);        // Reset The Current Viewport

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);    // Select The Projection Matrix
glLoadIdentity();               // Reset The Projection Matrix

// Calculate The Aspect Ratio Of The Window
gluPerspective(30.0f,(GLfloat)640/(GLfloat)480,0.3f,200.0f);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);     // Select The Modelview Matrix
glLoadIdentity();
```

also check the second [Nehe tutorial](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/your_first_polygon/13002/) it will help you to start with OpenGL for very basic stuff like drawing primitives such as triangle, square etc...

Comment: Thanks. I don't know what glViewPort does but casting to GLfloat did the trick for me.

Comment: Ok i have just read that when an OpenGL context is first attached to a window, width and height are set to the dimensions of that window so it might be not necessary. As for the glViewport command it defines a transformation from normalized device coordinates (that is, post-projection matrix coordinates with the perspective divide applied) to window coordinates

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`gluOrtho2D`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368673%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to generate a correct orthogonal projection matrix, in your case `gluOrtho2D(0,640,0,480)`, this is assuming you want a square in **2D** and not 3D.

This will of course change your coordinate system from (0,1),(0,1) to (0,640),(0,480).